# "Deploy to cloud run" to existing miniconda enviroment using dockerfile

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, miniconda

I created a sever on google cloud and created a miniconda environment to test my API and worked. But to do the "Deploy to cloud run" did not. There is a way to do the deploy by dockerfile on an existing conda environment on google cloud? If yes, please, where I find a tutorial or an example?

Or will be something like this:

```
FROM python:3.8


USER myuser #an existing user
WORKDIR /home/myuser

RUN conda activate venv # an existing miniconda environment

ENV PATH="/home/myuser/.local/bin:${PATH}"

COPY --chown=myuser:myuser . .

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Comment: What did not work? Do you have an error?

Comment: Cloud Run requires a web server to process HTTP Requests. Your Dockerfile is starting a python program. Does that program contain a web server? Edit your question with details, main.py and error message from Cloud Logging.

Answer (score 1):

There might be an existing environment in some VM, but not in this container. And a `Dockerfile` might not be enough, but this may require a [`cloudbuild.yaml`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-build-samples/blob/main/quickstart-deploy/cloudbuild.yaml), where the `image` needs Python 3.8 and miniconda installed. In case the default Python 3.8 image does not provide miniconda, you'll have to build a custom image first - which then can be used. I mean, one can use the `Dockerfile` to build the custom Docker image and `cloudbuild.yaml` to cloud build/run it. In order to run commands post-deploy (as it may be required), the container needs to know about them.

Besides, setting up a per-user environment inside a container is generally strange,
because system services usually do not care much about a per-user environment.